# Building hadoop with Maven error: maven-javadoc-plugin

Tags: java, hadoop

I am building Hadoop using following command:

```
mvn package -Pdist,native,docs -DskipTests -Dtar
```

It gives following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.8.1:jar (module-javadocs) on project hadoop-annotations: MavenReportException: Error while creating archive:
[ERROR] Exit code: 1 - /tmp/hadoop-2.5.0-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-annotations/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/classification/InterfaceStability.java:27: error: unexpected end tag: </ul>
[ERROR] * </ul>
```

This error is happening while building the `Apache Hadoop Annotations` module:

```
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Main ................................ SUCCESS [1.000s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Project POM ......................... SUCCESS [1.350s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Annotations ......................... FAILURE [2.393s]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the error is with the javadoc plugin you can skip it by specifying `-Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true`.

This will build it without generating java docs.